# CSS: is it possible to have a non breaking space with :after?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have the :after content to be stuck to the end of the "hydrique" word, in order not to have line breaks in between.

```
.openPage:after {
    content: '◱'; //'⎘
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 1.23em;
}

<a class="openPage">Manque d’eau – Stress hydrique</a>
```

*EDIT 1* I adjusted the width to have 2 lines.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/4X73W/

*EDIT 2* The first part of the style was missing; that is what makes the line breaks.  I have updated the jsFiddle accordingly.

```
openPage:after {
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.0em;

    content: '◱';
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 1.23em;
}
```

*EDIT 3*  I added a screen shot of the current result.  You can see that the two first lines are OK, while the third is broken.

[image]

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/1/

Comment: Can you explain it please?

Comment: @NicoO Well, no, change width: 240x, to width: 120px to see that you'll overflow the column. (I edited my original jsFiddle to make things clearer about that very point.

Comment: I have no clue what you are want to achieve. "line breaks in between"? You want your icon at the very end of the word? Or what?

Comment: @askrufus see the fiddle. There must be a non breaking space between the last word of the sentence ans the icon.

Comment: If you remove the white-space in your code right after hydrique and before</a>, your generated content will be attached to the last word http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/7/ . you may add a padding too for a better visual http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/8/

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, this was driving me crazy! I was thinking i'm completely stupid. Why you don't just remove the empty space in your code?

Comment: Ok, something is weird. In my actual code, I don't have this space… That doesn't solve my problem. I'm trying to simulate the same issue I've got in my actual code. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `display:inline-block;` to `.openPage:after` and on your div element you should raise the width.

Comment: It's no question to increase or adjust the width of a given column. Additionally, adding display: inline-block makes now difference.

Comment: And what if you add position:absolute;right:-15px; to your after and position:relative; to your div ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of the extra space before the closing </a>

[Edit 2 answer]
The display: inline-block is messing it up for you.
Remove it, and use padding to achieve your proper boxing around the icon.

Comment: as i commented http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/7/, http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/8/ for the width, better use EM than px :) http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/9/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's doable in the way you want, which is that the `:after` content becomes part of the flow as if it were part of the `a` link text and in addition isn't treated as a hyphenation opportunity.

You can get at least part of the way there by setting `position:relative` on your `.openPage` class and `position:absolute` on your `.openPage:after` pseudo-element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/9MRx3/)**

```
.openPage {
    position: relative;
}

.openPage:after {
    content: '◱';
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 1.23em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The problem with that solution, of course, is that it takes your `:after` content out of the document flow, which means it can bleed over the right margin of your container, as you can see in the example where I changed your div width to 115px.

I'll leave this here as a partial solution even though it doesn't really accomplish what you want, in hopes that someone may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/17/)

CSS for the fix:

```
.openPage:after {
    content: '◱';
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Please, take the latest fiddle as I have updated it in [edit 2] @charles

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/4X73W/18/) by adding some padding if that's acceptable.

Comment: Alas, the container varies in the app, I can't do that. @charles

Comment: Does it need to be 20px wide then? You're literally trying to fit something where it just can't, 20px tall where your line height is only 13.5px.

Comment: I have added a screen shot for you to look at hat I've got (see the too first are ok). @charles

Comment: so you're just wanting to turn off word wrapping? Thats `.openPage {white-space:nowrap;}`

Comment: Sometimes, the link is long and don't fit if not split, hence my issue. I'm ok to be split, but only in between words.

Comment: I'd add in line breaks manually then with <br />. That'd _seem_ like the correct way to do it for me. No need for anything fancy with css.

Answer (score 0):

add  `display: inline;` to `.openPage:after` and increase width for div to 150px( or whatever is required.

```
.openPage:after {
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.0em;

    content: '◱';
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 1.23em;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the inline-block in favor to inline, I lose the disk shape around the icon @ashish

Comment: I dont see any loss to icon shape. can you pls recheck it.

Comment: you can also try width: auto; for div and you can keep inline-block for openPage:after